# How to maintain unique timestamp at PUTFILE processor in NIFI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, etl, apache-nifi

I have some csv data which needs to put into a location with unique file name with specific file naming convention.

Flow sequence

1. Merge record -> At here the csv rows will get merged and gets forward to the update attribute processor.
2. Update Attribute -> When the merged flowfile content(collection of csv row) flows through the update attribute processor, the current timestamp with the below syntax will get assigned to the "filename" flowfile-attribute.
   syntax: Test-${now():format("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", "IST")}.csv
3. PutSftp -> Now at putsftp server whatever the flow file received form update attribute is getting published to an remote server.

Issue statement:

My remote server has restriction with the file name format and it should be in specific as defined like:
syntax: Test-${now():format("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS", "IST")}.csv
Egg: Test-202104041836555.csv

So at the update attribute processor the multiple flowfiles (merged content) are getting assigned same filename due to thread processing multiple flowfiles at same instance of timestamp and while placing into sftp  server the csv file is getting failed to process and place into the remote server as there is already existing file with same name.

Note:
I have nothing to do with conflict resolve strategies in putsftp processor as my sftp server client has a tight dependency on the file naming format.

Image for reference of the processor sequence flow:

[image: Flow diagram]

Update Attribute processor properties:

[image: Update Attribute processor properties]

Comment: Set `Conflict Resolution=FAIL` property for `PutSFTP`, add `ControlRate` and feed failed files from PutSFTP to ControlRate. Configure `ControlRate` to wait for a minute and then feed back to `ChangeFileName`. Basically it is kind of a loop to get new current timestamp for only failed files.

Comment: your solution sounds good, but one corner case again here- suppose file goes to failed state and then again goes to update attribute (now if there were another flowfile also may exist in procesing) and again this case may occur right?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by introduction ControrRate processor.
Configuration of ControlRate processor:

[image]

By pumping only one flowfile at a instance / point of time to the udpate attribute processor, am able to achieve assigning unique timestamp for each flow file.

Updated flow diagram:

[image]